# How to capture log output from Flux in these unit tests?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am checking out the example code in this project https://github.com/balamaci/reactor-core-playground#simple-operators

Here is a typical function in the source code

```
@Test
public void delayElements() {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    log.info("Starting");
    Flux.range(0, 5)
            .doOnNext(val -> log.info("Emitted {}", val))
            .delayElements(Duration.of(2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
            .subscribe(
                    tick -> log.info("Tick {}", tick),
                    (ex) -> log.info("Error emitted"),
                    () -> {
                        log.info("Completed");
                        latch.countDown();
                    });

    Helpers.wait(latch);
}
```

I want to be able to see the log output like `Error emitted`.

However if i run `mvn test` I cannot see any stdout output at all.

I have tried to enable log capture in the surefire plugin but it also does not achieve anything

```
+        <plugin>
+          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
+          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
+          <configuration>
+            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
+          </configuration>
+        </plugin>
```

There is a property file in the resource

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=HH:mm:ss:SSS
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showShortLogName=true
```

But the output is still

```
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.balamaci:reactor-playground >-------------------
[INFO] Building Reactor-Core Playground 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ reactor-playground ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/antkong/experiments/flux/reactor-core-playground/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ reactor-playground ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ reactor-playground ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ reactor-playground ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ reactor-playground ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.657 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-21T18:27:58+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, how can I capture the log output?

Comment: Provide a minimal, reproducible example; I don't have the ability to fix code I can't see.

Comment: The link to the repo is in the question. It is as minimal as it can get.

Comment: I would highly recommend using the reactor-test project when running your tests. You'll get access to the [`StepVerifier`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html) so that you can actually run assertions on your flows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be lack of `Test` word in class names, so they are not ran at all. Commands like `mvn test -Dtest=Part02SimpleOperators`, where you provide a name, work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don’t have any logger implementation on classpath. Try adding the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and create `resources/logback.xml`

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but it does not seem to work. I have added the `mv test` output to the question.